# material-ui input select attribute hides the body overflow-y scroll - react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui v3.1.2 with react js v16.5.2. In my page, there are many places where i am using `<TextField>` with `select` attribute. So, whenever i click on that `TextField` and when the dropdown appears, it hides my parent vertical scrollbar causing some ui shifting towards right as it hides the scrollbar. I don't want that to happen, so any solution would be of great help.

Here is the screenshot of before opening the dropdown,

[image: Screenshot_before_dropdown]

Here is the screenshot of after opening the dropdown,
[image: Screenshot_after_dropdown]

Comment: I think, it's default behaviour of material ui select component. If you use native, you will get default behaviour of browser. You can try same thing on https://material-ui.com/api/select/

Comment: So, can i achieve that default behaviour, while using mateiral ui select component? @KishanMundha

Comment: @VikasValechha Did you find any solution of the issue?

Comment: Also interested if you found the cause of this?

Answer (score 13):

A workaround for this issue can be to use the Select component of material-ui and use the 'disableScrollLock: true' property. But in that case, the scroll bar will not disappear on opening select, so the whole page will be scrollable while the select options are open.

```
<Select
    MenuProps={{
          disableScrollLock: true,
        }}
...
/>
```

Comment: I have a problem using Select component, can someone solve this for <TextField select> component

Comment: l found out the solution, thanks! it's answered above

Comment: This is the correct answer for the problem described above.

Answer (score 4):

I have a problem using Select component, so The solution using a textField:

```
 <TextField select SelectProps={{ MenuProps: { disableScrollLock: true } }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class into your header, It'll solve your issue

```
<header class="mui-fixed"></header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering only if it helps somebody.

By default whenever you open the dropdown using mat `<Menu></Menu>` it will add `overflow: hidden;` to the body node.
One possible solution is that you add `overflow-y: auto !important;` on the body element and this also worked for me.

**For example:**
[image: Body with scroll]

Here you see I have added `overflow-y: auto !important;` in my body style

---

---

[image: Mat replacing scroll]

Now here you see mat is automatically assigning `overflow: hidden;` to my body element. Which I have catered by `!important;`